# Geo Location based on IP Address - PHP

Tags: php, geolocation, geoip

We're looking for a fast and accurate way to get the visitors location based on their IP.

We have tried ipinfodb.com but their API made our website severely lag when making the API call.

What else can I do?

Comment: Top answer contained stolen content from https://css-tricks.com/snippets/php/get-geo-ip-information/

Answer (score 3):

Try this one http://ip.codehelper.io/

Here is PHP code. The code will caching your request automatic, so your server will not send multiple request. Return IP Address, Country, City and more information.

```
<?php
// Required Libraries
require_once("ip.codehelper.io.php");
require_once("php_fast_cache.php");

// New Class
$_ip = new ip_codehelper();

// Detect Real IP Address & Location
$real_client_ip_address = $_ip->getRealIP();
$visitor_location       = $_ip->getLocation($real_client_ip_address);

// Output result
echo $visitor_location['Country']."";
echo "<pre>";
print_r($visitor_location);
```