# PHP - Detect country

Tags: php, geo, country, country-codes

I want to detect my visitor's country.

And I have found the solution at Google,
but the result is nothing.

Can you help me?

Comment: I highly doubt Google returned you nothing useful.

Comment: Sure, but i can't found what i want

Comment: Or this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7766978/geo-location-based-on-ip-address-php

Comment: So, which answer did you like?

Comment: guess u were googling " help me google, i don't know how to detect country in PHP, Please help me i dont know how to use google "

Comment: @Osa don't be foolish, of course not !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    <?php 
// Author: www.easyjquery.com 
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; 
// remember chmod 0777 for folder 'cache' 
$file = "./cache/".$ip; 
if(!file_exists($file)) { 
    // request 
    $json = file_get_contents("http://api.easyjquery.com/ips/?ip=".$ip."&full=true"); 
    $f = fopen($file,"w+"); 
    fwrite($f,$json); 
    fclose($f); 
} else { 
    $json = file_get_contents($file); 
} 

$json = json_decode($json,true); 
echo "<pre>"; 
print_r($json); 

?>
```

[Demo Link](http://api.easyjquery.com/test/demo-ip.php)

Comment: Kelley can you edit your answer and add some local solution of it, i don't want to use external solution
I will accept you if you can do it

Comment: Hi Michael, Check here, the info is available to also download the js file so you can host the solution yourself, hope that helps :) http://www.easyjquery.com/2012/11/geo-api-detect-clients-ip-country-city-with-javascript-php/

Comment: type 2 -- fopen(./cache/72.193.132.49): failed to open stream: No such file or directory -- at line 9

Answer (score 7):

Here is my way of getting the country along with the ip of the person visiting.

```
// this is where you get the ip
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

// this is where you include the code that gets the country
// you can find the code for this file on the link below    
include("geoiploc.php");

// this is where you create the variable that get you the name of the country
$country = getCountryFromIP($ip, " NamE ");
```

[php geo ip loc does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16702162/php-geo-ip-loc-does-not-work)

Hope this helps.

May the code be with you!

Update:

Here is another method I've been using

```
    $json = file_get_contents('http://ipinfo.io/' . $this->getIP());
    $data = json_decode($json);
    return $data->country;
```

There is also this service, but I found the one above much better...

```
    'http://getcitydetails.geobytes.com/GetCityDetails?fqcn=' . $this->getIP()
```

Here is a good way to get the ip:

```
private function getIP() {
    $server_keys = [
        'HTTP_CLIENT_IP',
        'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR',
        'HTTP_X_FORWARDED',
        'HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP',
        'HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR',
        'HTTP_FORWARDED',
        'REMOTE_ADDR'
    ];

    foreach ($server_keys as $key) {
        if (array_key_exists($key, $_SERVER) === true) {
            foreach (explode(',', $_SERVER[$key]) as $ip) {
                if (filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP) !== false) {
                    return $ip;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps someone!

Comment: here is the complete documentation for the geoiploc.php file: http://chir.ag/projects/geoiploc/

Comment: Thanks Daniel, if you use the geoiploc ...
Are you get it slowly ?

Comment: I do use it, I use it for logging the visits for my website and its nice to have the country stored. What do you mean if I get it slowly?