# if else in php for choose and play iframe from two option

Tags: javascript, php, iframe

I want to add an auto select one `iframe` "which is running" between two to play videos on my website.
I need decision block in PHP/JavaScript to automatically choose 1 `iframe` from the two.
In some countries the videos plays from one `iframe` and in other countries it plays from both iframes.

So I want to add a way so any user from anywhere can watch videos.

Normally I'm using this one directly

```
<div id="video" style="margin-top:10px;"><iframe width="940" height="420" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo $_GET['v'] ;?>?autoplay=1&vq=medium&modestbranding=1&showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

But now I want to add one more `iframe`, which is here

```
<div id="video" style="margin-top:10px;"><iframe width="940" height="420" src="http://www.v.ytapi.com/embed/<?php echo $_GET['v'] ;?>?autoplay=1&vq=medium&modestbranding=1&showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

plz help me.
thanks,
Medipalace

Comment: Do you know which video to display server-side? If so, that's PHP. If you only know this client-side, you need Javascript. Which is it?

Comment: Also you need to show us what you have tried and detail specificallt what isnt working or what you cannot figure out.

Comment: Dear i wants this that if someone
click on a video for watch it than first iframe automatic work for play video.if not than automatic second iframe should work.like if else

Comment: or you can help me by write a code some like this.if any user come from these location(pakistan,uae etc) than iframe 1 works,and for all other countries iframe 2 should automatic work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find many responses to know the country in this post:
[PHP - Detect country](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14414705/php-detect-country&ved=0CCMQFjAB&usg=AFQjCNH4MY-hmCHnIWw7nNjQBqx-DHDECQ&sig2=H5D0hIHVow6a9I1vT8CHsg)

For example you can use the api hostip

```
$country = '';
$IP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
if (!empty($IP)) {
$country =                  file_get_contents('http://api.hostip.info/country.php?ip='.$IP);
 }
```

After you can test the country :
    if($country== "england") {
     // your code
    }

Comment: Thank you very much sir.You helped me alot for this.