# how to redirect users to different index.php pages based on their states location

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, geolocation

We had different index pages for different states of users.

```
    let my site is some www.example.com
```

So if user is requesting from Andhra Pradesh state then he needs to load apindex.php. If he is from Tamilnadu then he needs to load tamilindex.php. How can I accomplish this? Is it possible to identify users request on server side so that we can redirect to required page or else we have to handle it in client side? I am new to this redirection, any approach to do this redirection.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When they first enter your site ask them which state they come from and load accordingly?

Comment: Looks like this is already answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7766978/geo-location-based-on-ip-address-php)

Answer (score 1):

With php you can achieve

## use this API http://ipinfo.io

```
function ip_details($IPaddress) 
{
    $json       = file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$IPaddress}");
    $details    = json_decode($json);
    return $details;
}

$IPaddress  =   $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$details    =   ip_details("$IPaddress");

//echo $details->city;   #Tamilnadu  
//echo $details->country;  
//echo $details->org;      
//echo $details->hostname; 

header('location: http://'.$details->city.'.index.com');
```

Answer (score 0):

we can achieve this by php script and third party application to check state on basis of IP. by using that we can redirect user to particular index page.

[Geo Location based on IP Address - PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7766978/geo-location-based-on-ip-address-php)

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/php/detect-location-by-ip/